# Outlook - Expand bullet point to show more text?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I want to send an email that will have 5 topics I need to talk about.
Each topic will have a good 2-3 paragraphs of spiel.

Id like to have each bullet point expandable, so that the reader could click a little plus button (or similar) to expand out the spiel beneath each bullet point.

Is this do-able in Outlook 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not by itself. Unlike Outlook 2003 and before, Outlook 2007/2010 use only Word as their default editor, and even that does not do it.

You can use an add-in to create new styles to do it, which I would think would then be available to you in Outlook. See the following web pages:

http://www.instantfundas.com/2010/09/create-collapsibleexpandable-sections.html

http://www.moreaddin.com/

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/933793